# Sql query to fetch data from table based on a given condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables **Table1- Newname**  **Table2- Oldname** with below sample data

**Table1- Newname**

```
id Name
1  Ram
2  Sam  
3  Jam
4  Dam
5  Liam
```

**Table2- Oldname**

```
id Name
1  Kim
2  Sam  
3  Tam
4  Lim
5  Liam
```

Now I want to fetch records in **sequence** such a way that **first** it will list all the names from **Newname
table** that are **not present** in **Oldname table** and then show the names that are **same in both Newname and Oldname table.**

Like Below based on above data

```
id Name
1  Ram
3  Jam
4  Dam
2  Sam
5  Liam
```

Can someone with SQL/DB experience please help me with this query.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What has this got to do with Java？  What have you tried so far?

Comment: And sql <> mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`. The `UNION ALL` command combines the result set of two or more SELECT statements:

```
SELECT n.name 
from newname n left join oldname o on n.name = o.name 
where o.name is null
union all
SELECT n.name
from newname n inner join oldname o on n.name = o.name
```

Comment: @user7350714 . . . Without an `order by`, this is not guaranteed to return rows in any particular order.  The upvote is curious.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results in a particular order, then you should have an explicit `order by`.  Otherwise the result set is not guaranteed to be in any particular order:

```
select n.name
from newname n left join
     oldname o
     on n.name = o.name and n.id = o.id
order by (o.name is null) desc, n.id;
```

From your description, it is not clear if the ids need to match as well as the names.  In your case, if they match they have the same ids.